# Fetch API work on POSTMAN and express server but does not work on React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to fetch API by using axios get method. This is the link http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?language_filter=en.

My backend is Node js with Express and frontend is React js. It's working fine when I run in Postman and also Express server (It shows the data). But When I render it in React component, it does not show anything.

When I checked the React component's network status, it shows pending. I don't know, What I am doing wrong since I don't get any error.

**This is my Express server setup**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");
app.use(cors());

app.get("/events", async (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get("http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?language_filter=en")
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Server's package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "myhelsinki",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is for educational purpose",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "alak",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

**This is my React component.**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Events = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    events();
  }, []);
  const [state, setstate] = React.useState([]);
  const events = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/events")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => setstate(response.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map(list => {
        return <li>{list.id}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Events;
```

**This is React's package.json file. Ps. I have tried proxy settings in package.json but it did not work as well.**

```
{
  "name": "myhelsinki",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what you are getting error in backend log ???

Comment: Hi 

@Jayce444 fixed my backend problem. I did not send the response to the front end. But I am facing new problem in react frontend where its says "GET http://localhost:5000/events 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: do console.log() in your backend as well.So,it will help you to figure out what happen here catch(err => { console.log(err)  return res.status(500).send(err)} );

Comment: and let me know what you are getting in your log

Comment: Back end status is 200 ok. I did not get any error. I think I am getting error from React settings. But don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I used proxy settings on React's package.json file:  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000". 

And In the component I used async function.

`const events = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/events");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.data);
  };`

Comment: .then(res => res.json()) problem is here you are trying res.json() instead of res.data.json()

Comment: I did not get it mate. Did you mean my backend or frontend :) ?

Comment: @PrakashKarena I getting error on my frontend: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

`const fectingData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/events");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data.data);
      setstate(data);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  };
`
Don't know what I doing wrong.

Comment: .then(res => console.log(res)) give me log of your res

Comment: Yes sir. Have check this is api link: http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?language_filter=en. was my front end set up wrong?

Comment: my god.. you are trying to access many recoreds at a time this api return much more recoreds which can be time consuming so your server return error because of more time consuming

Comment: try to get only some record and then apply pagination on it

Comment: my backend logs:` {
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    server: 'Cowboy',
    connection: 'close',
    'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'master-only',
    date: 'Tue, 21 Jan 2020 06:20:28 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '4135857',
    via: '1.1 vegur'
  },

Comment: I never done pagination. Do you have suggestion, how to do that?

Comment: right now what you are getting error in your frontend ???

Comment: Yes. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: here is my frontend is my code: `const fectingData = async () => { try { const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/events"); const data = await response.json(); console.log(data.data); setstate(data); } catch (err) { alert(err); } }`

Comment: http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/doc#/v1events/listAll

Comment: Now I limited the records fetching. http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?limit=5&language_filter=en

Comment: But I am still getting error?

Comment: wait i'm writing ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Events = () => {

 const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingData();
  }, []);

  const fetchingData = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/events")
      .then(response => {

         console.log('response',response.data)

         setEvents(response.data.data)
       }) // you have array in your response.data so add your data here
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

//do console.log
 console.log('events',events)

  return (
    <div>
      {events.map(list => {
        return <li>{list.id}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Events;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206338/discussion-on-answer-by-prakash-karena-fetch-api-work-on-postman-and-express-ser).

Answer (score 1):

Well you're not sending the response from the back end to the front end, you're just printing it. You need to actually return the response to the front end, like this:

```
app.get("/events", async (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get("http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?language_filter=en")
    .then(response => res.send(response))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});
```

Comment: @dam well if you're getting a 500 that means the `.catch` in the `/events` route is triggering. Print out that error and see what the reason is for it failing.